# Is there a way to form only ortho product without using fractional distillation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, distillation, separation-techniques

> Using benzene and ethane as your only source of carbon in the final molecule, synthesize the following using any useful reagents. Reaction must form pure ortho compound.
>
> [image: 4‐[(1E)‐2‐(2‐propylphenyl)diazen‐1‐yl]phenol]

I have to form the product shown in the picture with only the ortho position formed. I'm not sure how to do this other than with fractional distillation, but I doubt that's what my professor is expecting from me, so there must be another way I am not thinking of.

Comment: Post your suggestions for the route by which you'll make this product and it will be easier to suggest how to get only the product drawn.

Comment: Is there any practical feasibility constraint? Any limit on number of steps? 'cause my shortest synthesis has at least ~15 steps with a lot of reagents.